# Rails 3.1 simple question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to use the nested_form gem for my application that uses Rails 3.1 rc5. When I install the gem there is a js file placed in public/javascripts. i am supposed to place this line in my app: `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form" %>` would this line let my app access the js file or should i do `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "/javascripts/nested_form" %>`

Answer (score 1):

try this

In config/application.rb

uncomment this line

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(nested_form.js)
```

All that this line is doing is loading your nested_form.js as a default, you can add many files like %w(nested_form.js javascript1.js javascript2.js)

Then in views/layouts add this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Now the nested_form.js will get loaded with all the defaults .js files

Comment: javascript expansions do not work with the asset pipeline turned on in rails 3.1

Answer (score 0):

If the asset pipeline is turned on in your application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Try putting the nested_form.js file in /app/assets/javascripts.

Then it will get included with your other javascripts if you use the line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in your views.
```